# Joomla 3.5 + EXTman and DOCman on IIS 8.5 issue with file permissions

Tags: iis, joomla, joomla-component, joomla3.5

I recently uploaded the DOCman component to my Joomla website, did the installation process as instructed on the Joomlatools website (EXTman first, DOCman second). Both installations gave me a Correct Installation message but when I click on the Components menu to check each component it starts downloading an index.php file.

I tried re-installing the components. Did not work.

I made a backup and uploaded my website to a Linux server. Issue didn't appear.

So, I'm guessing is a file permission issue on my server (IIS 5.8). I checked and all folders in my server are writable (used this as a reference: http://joomla-tips.org/configuration-tricks/joomla-and-windows-file-permissions.html). Tried this several times with multiple combinations, and reinstalled the components in Joomla. Didn't work.

I cannot uninstall the components because EXTman is the component to uninstall DOCman and IT DOES NOT WORK.

Just to point out, I had not had writting/reading issues in my server before this. I have virtuemart and other plugins installed that just ran smoothly.

Any idea of where I might check?

Comment: Docman is a paid component, so you can first try their forum. They may be able to help you.

Comment: I have but their response was, and I quote... "unfortunately not an expert on Windows servers". I cannot make the site live as I am on a corporate network. 

Did the install on a Linux server and as the problem didn't appear it's not worth it to make them check that site. 

I've narrowed my problem to a PHP configuration on IIS... working on that.

Comment: Unfortunately its difficult to answer as thats a paid component and we dont have access to it. You can check this link it may help you https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994592(v=ws.11).aspx